# jquery div refresh when target content loads at body-onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML file with:

```
<div id='mcontent'></div>
```

Every 5 seconds, I want it to refresh with my content at content.php

```
setTimeout(function(){
window.location = window.location;
$( "#mcontent" ).load('content.php');
}, 5000);
```

content.php populates a table with SQL information:

```
<body onload="populateInfoTable();">
<table id='InfoTable'></table>
</body>
```

The function "populateInfoTable" fills InfoTable with rows like this:

```
document.getElementById('InfoTable').innerHTML='<td>' . $sqlData . '</td>';
```

The problem is, when setTimeout refreshes #mcontent, it just puts in:

```
<table id='InfoTable'></table>
```

Even though the actual contents of content.php (when loaded) look like this:

```
<table id='InfoTable><tr><td>cat</td><td>dog</td></tr></table>
```

So it seems like jquery's load does not wait for content.php's "body onload".

I also want to refresh the page title with the number of items in the table, like "(2) Animals".

Comment: From your description of the issue it sounds like the structure of the content.php file is itself loading through JS. In which case what you're trying to do won't work, as the JS of the result is not executed. Even if it did, it would make more sense to return the HTML content directly. That aside, AJAX polling itself is a bad idea as it places extra load on your server. I'd suggest using Websockets or server sent events if you want to keep the server data and UI in close sync.

Comment: With the current setup, is there any way I can refresh this data (without a meta page reload) using an interval function? It doesn't need to be jquery on div, but just some way to re-populate the table data every X minutes. We aren't worried about the server load because it won't be heavily used.

Comment: There's no way to answer that question without seeing the code of content.php to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. For some reason I passed the SQL output to Javascript and did all my functions there. I should have just done the functions server-side in PHP and echo'd the table results in a loop. I will rewrite those. Thank you!